# Long time to Rotate bitmap and full screen image?

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, camera, android-glide

Using costume camera and it return byte code for me so I am convert byte code to bitmap and then rotate it but that is using 5 to 4 second for rotate bitmap after display image in imageview how to solve it

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(90);
Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOrg,width,height,true);
Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap , 0, 0, scaledBitmap .getWidth(), scaledBitmap .getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

If I am save capture image and get it but image is small.
I am using glide library so image is displaying fast but image is small

```
Glide
    .with(Edit_Image.this )
    .load(Product.getCaptureImage())
    .transform( new RotateTransformation(getApplicationContext(), 90f ))
    .into(imgMain);
```

Comment: If you just want to rotate by 90 degrees try transposing the matrix instead of rotating it.

Comment: I am use it but it not work for me .. so please give some more solution..

Comment: Glide is not a good choice for your use case, because it does not support rotation as the image is displayed; instead, **transform()** uses `Bitmap.createBitmap()` which may be slow and expensive on memory.